# C++ Multiple Definitions of Blank Header FIle

Tags: c++, linker, header-files

I've been searching around for the answer to this but so far nothing has worked.

I have two files that were provided to me for a Parser assignment, lex.h and parse.h. The lex.h file was used in a previous assignment and works fine, the parse.h file is giving me issues. The parse.h file looks like this:

```
#ifndef PARSE_H_
#define PARSE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

#include "lex.h"

//using std::map;
map<string, bool> defVar;

namespace Parser {
    bool pushed_back = false;
    LexItem pushed_token;

    static LexItem GetNextToken(istream& in, int& line) {
        if( pushed_back ) {
            pushed_back = false;
            return pushed_token;
        }
        return getNextToken(in, line);
    }

    static void PushBackToken(LexItem & t) {
        if( pushed_back ) {
            abort();
        }
        pushed_back = true;
        pushed_token = t;   
    }
}

static int error_count = 0;

void ParseError(int line, string msg)
{
    ++error_count;
    cout << line << ": " << msg << endl;
}

extern bool Prog(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool StmtList(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool Stmt(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool PrintStmt(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool IfStmt(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool Var(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool AssignStmt(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool ExprList(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool Expr(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool Term(istream& in, int& line);
extern bool Factor(istream& in, int& line);

#endif /* PARSE_H_ */
```

Analyzer Class

```
#include <regex>
#include "lex.h"

/** 
 * Relates token type to string
 */
static std::map<Token, std::string> tokenPrint {
 // Code not provided for readability
};

/** 
 * Operator overloading << for Token object
 */
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const LexItem& tok) {
    // Code not provided for readability
}

/**
 * Current token is used to set previous token before returned
 * Previous token is used to compare to the current token and check
 * for invalid arangment such as no begin token.
 */
LexItem currentToken;
LexItem previousToken;

/**
 * Return the next token within a file
 */
LexItem getNextToken(istream& in, int& linenum) {
    enum TokenState { START, INID, INSTRING, ININT, INREAL, INCOMMENT, SIGN} lexstate = START;
    std::string lexeme;
    char character;
    // Code not provided for readability
}
```

Parse.cpp

```
#include "parse.h"

bool Prog(istream& in, int& line) {
    return false;
}

bool StmtList(istream& in, int& line) {
    return false;
}
// All the rest return false too
```

Tester.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include "parse.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Reads file and handles errors
    // Code not provided for readability
    while (true) {
         Parse::getNextToken(file, lineNumber);
    }
}
```

I have an Analyzer.cpp file that uses lex.h as a header for the Analyzer and I have a Parse.cpp that uses parse.h for the Parser. In the main program I use the parse.h header file.

I keep getting a multiple definition error with defVar, Parse::pushed_back, Parser::pushed_token, and ParseError(...). I cannot edit lex.h or parse.h as they are given to me and can only change the contents of Analyzer.cpp, Parser.cpp, and Tester.cpp. I can post all the code if necessary.

I'm fairly new to c++ but all the header files have the header guards and none of the functions are ever defined twice. I have looked at other problems but nothing seems to be working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, a [mre] would be very helpful.

Comment: The way this header is written, it can only be included in exactly one source file. If you attempt to include it in two or more files, you'll get multiple-definition linker errors.

Comment: Get `map<string, bool> defVar;` out of the header.